# How to Data put from database into table in different manner using php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to create a table where i can put some data from database.. But in different manner.(just like the image)[image]

In this pic.. "Csc 1st 101" is in first row first column and "csc 1st 102" is 2nd row 2nd column. 
I want to create in this manner. Please help me.

Comment: Show the SQL query to retrieve your desired data, then describe how you want that data to appear in your HTML table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>num1</th>
    <th>num2</th>
    <th>num3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

<?php
$perRow= 3;
$arr = array('Csc 1st 101', 'Csc 1st 102', 'Csc 1st 103', 'Csc 1st 201','Csc 1st 202','Csc 1st 203','Csc 1st 301','Csc 1st 302','Csc 1st 303');
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $i++;
    echo '<th>'. $value .'</th>';
    if ($i % $perRow == 0){
        echo   '</tr><tr>';}
}
?>
</table>
```

you can change $perRow if you want to show more values per row